# How to implement this lazy loading pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, lazy-loading

The following code illustrates the initial situation on which I want to improve:

```py
# expensive function execution returning a value
def f(x:int):
    print(f"f({x})")
    return 2*x

# the value is to be stored globally
gvar = f(3)

# this function uses the global variable
def g():
    doing_something_with(gvar)
    return
```

First of all I don't want `gvar` to be set immediately but upon the first time it is used (lazy loading):

```py
gvar = None

def g():
    gvar = f(3)
    doing_something_with(gvar)
    return
```

But also I don't want `gvar` to be set every time it is used as well:

```py
gvar = None

def g():
    if gvar is None:
      gvar = f(3)

    doing_something_with(gvar)
    return
```

And finally I want this to happen as transparently as possible - the result should be something similar to this:

```py
gvar = magic(f, 3)

def g():
    doing_something_with(gvar)
    return
```

So I can just use `gvar` as if it was a normal variable while it actually invisibly encapsulates a mechanism that will lazy load its value.

So if I call `g` several times:

```
g() # prints f(3)
g() # -
g() # -
```

Is that possible?

---

To give you further context. The practical scenario is a FastApi service where `g()` would represent a path. Several of those path operation functions might use the same global variable which should only be used once. To make the pattern more reusable and pluggable I would like the lazy loading to happen transparently.

Comment: Are you actually interested in having the global ``gvar`` (e.g. it being accessible from outside the module), or just in not executing the body of ``f`` every time?

Comment: the global variable holds data which is accessed by multiple functions executed independently within the API context. like GET /data will respond with this data and that request might be performed many times and simultaneously. but the data should only be loaded / made available once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to "cache" the results from the first call for each value:

```
from functools import lru_cache

import time

@lru_cache(maxsize=100)
def f(x):
    time.sleep(1)    
    return x*x

print(time.time())
for x in range(5):
    print(f(x))

print(time.time())
for x in range(5):
    print(f(x))

print(time.time())
```

Output:

```
1583003419.4904697 # startime
0                  # 1st calculation of 0*0
1                  # 1st calculation of 1*1
4                  # 1st calculation of 2*2
9                  # 1st calculation of 3*3
16                 # 1st calculation of 4*4
1583003424.496077  # takes 5'1 seconds due to the sleep(1) in the function (5*1s)
0                  # 2nd time 0*0 taken from cache
1                  # 2nd time 1*1 taken from cache
4                  # 2nd time 2*2 taken from cache
9                  # 2nd time 3*3 taken from cache
16                 # 2nd time 4*4 taken from cache
1583003424.496102 # takes almost no time, due results already in cache and taken from it
```

As for lazy: as long as you do not call the function it is lazy, don't get quite your point.

Comment: The use of time kinda distracts from seeing what your example is doing. Something like `print (f"Calculating {x} x {x}")` instead of `time.sleep` would have made this clearer

Comment: @sma The use of time shows that the thing only calculates once _including 1s sleep_ and caches the result so the second call is taken from the cache and returns immediately without recalculating/sleeping?